# Showing different nodes for same taxonomy terms on different URLs

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm facing this design issue regularly.

For example I've Jobs and Company node types. Both have one common taxonomy term reference field City.

Now when we go to a City term it will show both Jobs and Companies(I don't want this mixing).

I want that it show only Jobs or Companies(in different URL's)

One solution is to duplicate City vocabulary as City Jobs and second as City Companies.  Now I get what I want. But in programming it'll complicate as same city in both Vocabularies will have different term id's.

**What is the best way to achieve this?**

Comment: i usually use some special modules around this use case,  but I think for the most common use cases the views page solution by Dylan Tack is sufficient.

Comment: I think Dylan's answer is totally fine, and he deserves the bounty. My own situation often has some more requirements, that is: (1) Different views for different vocabularies. (2)  Different views for root-level terms than for lower-level terms (in a hierarchical vocabulary). (3) Having additional elements on the term page, e.g. the list of associated content plus some text field or image. (4)  Having a special layout on the term page. (5) Having a similar behavior for nodes instead of terms. I would share this stuff, but I think it should go into a separate question.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the Views module to create two different pages:

- "Jobs in City %1" at /jobs/%
- "Companies in City %1" /companies/%

Your Views will need a filter for content type, and a [contextual filter](https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/using-drupal-contextual-filters-views) for taxonomy term.  Next, use the [Rabbit hole](https://drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) module to make the /taxonomy/term/NNN pages disappear.

Comment: But how to add all those urls at say jobs/% in the XML sitemap?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can create a view based on  City term title

   Fields : Taxonomy term: Name -> Configure field: Taxonomy term: Name -> 
    REWRITE RESULT -> Output this field as a link -> taxonomy/term/[tid]/job
2. You can use the view module to create two different pages:

   a. view -> Page settings -> path -> taxonomy/term/%/job

   b. Contextual filters add  Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)   and    Content: Has taxonomy term ID depth modifier

   c.  Content: Type (= job)

   a1. view -> Page settings -> path -> taxonomy/term/%/company

   b1. b. Contextual filters add  Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)   and    Content: Has taxonomy term ID depth modifier

   c1.Content: Type (= company)

   when You click  Taxonomy term: Name (title) based on URL like taxonomy/term/1/job that redirect to taxonomy/term/%/job view page that return group of job content.

similarly group of company list

Answer (score 1):

Dylan Tack's answer is the right and the easiest way to achieve this functionality; If you don't want to use Views module you can solve this by custom module, like this (I didn't test it, correct it, if something is wrong with it):

```
function myModule_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['jobs/%taxonomy_term'] = array(
    'title' => 'Jobs',
    'page callback' => 'custom_page_by_jobs',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  $items['companies/%taxonomy_term'] = array(
    'title' => 'Companies',
    'page callback' => 'custom_page_by_companies',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

// Mimic of taxonomy_select_nodes() function;
function taxonomy_select_nodes_by_type($tid, $type, $pager = TRUE, $limit = FALSE, $order = array('t.sticky' => 'DESC', 't.created' => 'DESC')) {
  if (!variable_get('taxonomy_maintain_index_table', TRUE)) {
    return array();
  }
  $query = db_select('taxonomy_index', 't');
  $query->join('field_data_field_city', 'fdfc', 't.tid = fdfc.field_city_tid');
  $query->addTag('node_access');
  $query->condition('t.tid', $tid);
  $query->condition('fdfc.bundle', $type, '=');
  if ($pager) {
    $count_query = clone $query;
    $count_query->addExpression('COUNT(t.nid)');

    $query = $query->extend('PagerDefault');
    if ($limit !== FALSE) {
      $query = $query->limit($limit);
    }
    $query->setCountQuery($count_query);
  }
  else {
    if ($limit !== FALSE) {
      $query->range(0, $limit);
    }
  }
  $query->addField('t', 'nid');
  $query->addField('t', 'tid');
  foreach ($order as $field => $direction) {
    $query->orderBy($field, $direction);
    list($table_alias, $name) = explode('.', $field);
    $query->addField($table_alias, $name);
  }
  return $query->execute()->fetchCol();
}


function custom_page_by_type($term, $type) {
//  drupal_set_title($term->name);
//
//  $current = (object) array(
//    'tid' => $term->tid,
//  );
//
//  $breadcrumb = array();
//  while ($parents = taxonomy_get_parents($current->tid)) {
//    $current = array_shift($parents);
//    $breadcrumb[] = l($current->name, 'taxonomy/term/' . $current->tid);
//  }
//  $breadcrumb[] = l(t('Home'), NULL);
//  $breadcrumb = array_reverse($breadcrumb);
//  drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);
//
//  $uri = entity_uri('taxonomy_term', $term);
//  drupal_add_html_head_link(array('rel' => 'canonical', 'href' => url($uri['path'], $uri['options'])), TRUE);
//
//  drupal_add_html_head_link(array('rel' => 'shortlink', 'href' => url($uri['path'], array_merge($uri['options'], array('alias' => TRUE)))), TRUE);

  $build['term_heading'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div class="term-listing-heading">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    'term' => taxonomy_term_view($term, 'full'),
  );

  if ($nids = taxonomy_select_nodes_by_type($term->tid, $type, TRUE, 20)) {
    $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
    $build += node_view_multiple($nodes);
    $build['pager'] = array(
      '#theme' => 'pager',
      '#weight' => 5,
    );
  }
  else {
    $build['no_content'] = array(
      '#prefix' => '<p>',
      '#markup' => t('There is currently no content classified with this term.'),
      '#suffix' => '</p>',
    );
  }
  return $build;
}


function custom_page_by_jobs($taxonomy_term) {
  return custom_page_by_type($taxonomy_term, 'jobs');
}

function custom_page_by_companies($taxonomy_term) {
  return custom_page_by_type($taxonomy_term, 'companies');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

- Go to Views administration page: `admin/structure/views`
- Scroll down and **clone** *Taxonomy term* view.
- Under **Page Settings** change path to: `/taxonomy/term/%/%`
- Add new contextual filter under Advanced section
- Select **Content: type** and apply default settings
- **Rearrange** contextual filters so that the order is:

  1. Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)
  2. Content: Type
  3. Content: Has taxonomy term ID depth modifier
- That's it

If you visit the term page `taxonomy/term/%term`, you will still see all content types in a list. However, you can now filter this list with the name of the content type, for example:

- `taxonomy/term/%term/jobs`: will only list the jobs tagged with this term
- `taxonomy/term/%term/company`: will only list the companies tagged with this term.